# SQL Server 2008 to Amazon RDS SQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

As my website is going to AWS, can SQL Server 2008 R2 be imported to Amazon RDS for SQL Server ?

Appreciate if anyone can provide some guideline or any limitation . Thank You

Comment: Did you check [the RDS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) ? You can almost all migration/import techniques except attach/copy/detach. You can restore a backup, you can script the database, you can use SSIS to copy objects and data etc

Comment: The significant change is that you'd go from SQL Server 2008 R2, which is already out of mainstream support to a much newer version. New features like data complression, columnstore indexes and in-memory tables even in Express editions could result in huge performance improvements. You may end up needing a smaller instance than what you already have

Answer (score 0):

Backup and restore for Microsoft SQL Server databases can be done using full backup files (.bak files) in Amazon RDS service. You can create a full backup from your local server, store it on S3, and then restore it onto an existing Amazon RDS DB instance.

Limitations and Recommendations as given by AWS are as follows:

**The following are some limitations to using native backup and restore:**

> - You can't back up to, or restore from, an Amazon S3 bucket in a    different AWS Region than your Amazon RDS DB instance.
> - We strongly recommend that you don't restore backups from one time zone to a different time zone. If you restore backups from one time zone to a different time zone, you must audit your queries and applications for the effects of the time zone change.
> - Native backups of databases larger than 1 TB are not supported.
> - RDS supports native restores of databases up to 5 TB. Native restores    of databases on SQL Server Express are limited by the
>   MSSQL edition    to 10 GB or less.
> - You can't do a native backup during the maintenance window, or any time Amazon RDS is in the process of taking a snapshot of the database.
> - On Multi-AZ DB instances, you can only natively restore databases    that are backed up in full recovery model.
> - Calling the RDS procedures for native backup and restore within a    transaction is not supported.
> - Native backup files are encrypted with the specified AWS Key    Management Service key using the "Encryption-Only" crypto mode.
> - When you are restoring encrypted backup files, be aware that they
>   were encrypted with the "Encryption-Only" crypto mode.

You can refer to this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) for more details on migration.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 isn't available period. It's already out of mainstream support